# Vertically and horizontally aligning text over an image of variable size

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm not a CSS Ninja and without your genius solution I'll need to cook up some server-side solution to the problem which is:

- I have an image. The size of the image is variable. It can be 250x380
  or 640x480 or anything.
- I have to place some text at the center of the image. It has to be
  horizontally and vertically aligned.
- I need an HTML+CSS solution... well whatever works on client side.

Comment: Will you accept a JavaScript solution?

Comment: What browsers are you supporting?

Comment: You will probably have to use Javascript to get image size on client and to align text accordingly... It should be piece of cake if you use some jQuery plugin.

Comment: You can center it horizontally with CSS. But you'll have to know the image size to center vertically. Unless you're using tables, which have `vertical-align`- but I doubt your content is in a table.

Comment: What i've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/BFSH4/6/ not really an answer because you'll need to know the image height. Everything else should work.

Comment: Hey guys! I'm overwhelmed! Thanks for your answers... I never really considered any JavaScript solution *slaps forehead* but of course that should've done the trick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you're asking, using HTML, CSS and JavaScript:

1. Put the label you want in a property of the image, for instance the `alt` property
2. Write a function that creates a `div` element label and places it on top of the image
3. Run that function on all the images you want to have a label on top of

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/YnMfM/2/

My example requires JavaScript, but uses the jQuery library which is not mandatory. You can use pure JavaScript or any other library

Comment: P.S. While waiting for an answer I coded a page that actually gets the image I wanted, renders the text on it and returns the image. I solved the problem but honestly I still prefer your solution ^_^

Comment: Remember that when placing the label atop the image on the client side, the user can actually select the label text as well as save the image without the label if they wish, which is probably preferable. It will probably annoy your visitors if they try to save the pictures and the label sticks

Comment: Yo Codemonkey, I finally used your method, since the rendering on the server side was creating problems... the font size was varying depending on images (I'm guessing that was a resolution problem) and I think I've wasted enough time on this problem. Way to go for that solution - I used the one with tables after all ;)

Comment: Odd that you marked this one as the answer then :P But good to hear none the less, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do what you ask using only HTML and CSS. It's much dirtier than my other solution but it's kinda cool anyway.

1. Put the image inside a `div` with `position: relative`
2. Put a `div` inside a `table` inside a `div` inside the same div as the image
3. Stretch the `div` that's below the image across the wrapper using `position: absolute`
4. Set the table to 100% width and height and set its text align and vertical align to middle
5. Display the `div` inside the table as `inline-block` and style it as you wish

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Codemonkey/a52qx/1/

I can't vouch for the browser compatability. I bet Internet Explorer will throw fits, but I can't test that as I'm on a Ubuntu machine.

Comment: +1 for that great solution. Btw.: Works on IE8+ except of rgba ;) and Adobe Browserlab will help you testing on IEs: https://browserlab.adobe.com/

Comment: nice! can you explain why `.image-with-label` with `inline-block` makes this whole thing work, what are the rules/mechanism behind it?

Comment: @Blake: A table cell can be centred vertically inside a table row and an inline-block can be centred horizontally within a table cell. That's the only pure HTML/CSS way I know of to centre something "variable-sized" both vertically and horizontally. A table can't be placed absolutely, it only supports width and height, so it has to be placed within a div for absolute positioning. In the end, it's a great big mess of elements :)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML/CSS-only solution from Codemonkey/Hubro works, but you don't actually need to use tables. You can just set the relevant div's to `display:table` and `display:table-cell`.

Here's his example without tables:

https://jsfiddle.net/aphidesign/cwosvp9b/