# Using html/css to put text in center of each clickable image

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am looking to put a bit of text centered over a clickable image.  There is a lot of support for the issue of putting text over an image using HTML and CSS, but I can make none of the advice work for my issue.  I think this is because the 4 images that I want to do this to do not have a fixed location, but instead have a size relative to the window size. [This was particularly helpful, but for the J Query advice, the text didn't show up when I made the images clickable to links.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051794/vertically-and-horizontally-aligning-text-over-an-image-of-variable-size)

I realize that because the images change size relative to the screen dimensions, I may have to use J-Query to keep the text within the images. If your ideas go beyond the HTML/CSS, I'm happy to do that, too!

Thank a million in advance!!!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="Logo1.png"/>
    <div id="homeButtons">

        <a href="livetv.html">
            <img class="homeButtons" id="yellow" src="Content_Home/LiveTV.JPG"/> 
            TEXT
        </a>

        <a href="design.html">
            <img class="homeButtons" id="blue" src="Content_Home/DandC.JPG"/> 
        </a>

        <br>

        <a href="resume.html">
            <img class="homeButtons" id="green" src="Content_Home/Resume.JPG"/>
        </a>

        <a href="contact.html">
            <img class="homeButtons" id="pink" src="Content_Home/Contact.JPG"/> 
        </a>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Standards for ALL Pages */

body{
    background-color: black;
}

.logo{
    width:100%;
}

.defaultFont{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: yellow;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: black;
}

/* Home Page: home.html */

.homeButtons{
    /* applies to squares individually */
    width:30%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: .7;
    margin: 10px;
}

#homeButtons{
    /* centers all 4 squares as an entire entity, wouldn't work if was added to each individual square in the .homeButtons class above */
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

#yellow{
    border: 10px solid #FFE200;
}
#green{
    border: 10px solid #00B400;
}
#blue{
    border: 10px solid #006DF2;
}
#pink{
    border: 10px solid #F2007D;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please replicate this issue on JSFiddle ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KJKG2/

Answer (score 0):

Please search Stackoverflow for similar solved questions and try if you can solve the problem with its help.

Here is a good answer for a similar question - [Position text over image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275606/text-on-image-html-css)

And here is an awesome tutorial from Chris Coyier to achieve Text On Image

http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Hope it help you have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="Logo1.png"/>
    <div id="homeButtons">

        <a href="livetv.html">
            <div class='container'>
                 <img class="homeButtons" id="yellow" src="Content_Home/LiveTV.JPG"/> 
                 TEXT
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="design.html">
            <div class='container'>
                 <img class="homeButtons" id="blue" src="Content_Home/DandC.JPG"/> 
                 MORE TEXT
            </div>
        </a>

        <br>

        <a href="resume.html">
            <div class='container'>
            <img class="homeButtons" id="green" src="Content_Home/Resume.JPG"/>
            </div>
        </a>

        <a href="contact.html">
            <div class='container'>
            <img class="homeButtons" id="pink" src="Content_Home/Contact.JPG"/> 
            </div>
        </a>

    </div>
</body>
```

The Styles required:

```
.container {
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
}
.container img {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
}
```

Comment: I've tried a similar approach but unfortunately that messes up the spacing and location of the images. http://jsfiddle.net/KJKG2/